# A suitable tag for "Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've posted a [new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241507/what-does-multidimensional-buddy-do) about the new DLC of *Binding of Isaac: Rebirth*, which is called **Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth**.

Of course I needed a new tag, but the name [binding-of-isaac-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-afterbirth) exceeds the 25 characters limit.
I used [boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) tag for now.

Any suggestion for a better tag?

Comment: Related: [How to tag “Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth+”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12197/181240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/increase-tag-length-limit-to-32-or-35), I see no reason good reason not to synonymize [boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) with [binding-of-isaac-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-afterbirth).

Comment: The same should be done for [tag:boi-afterbirth+] and [tag:boi-antibirth]. We should probably also adjust the name of [tag:wrath-of-the-lamb].

Comment: Done: [[tag:the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth]], [[tag:the-binding-of-isaac-antibirth]],[[tag:the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+]], [[tag:the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth]]

Comment: @Robotnik Can you answer and mark [this related request for AB+](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12197/181240) as complete?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - I don't think it needs to be bumped - that meta is about the '+' symbol, there's been no change on that front. Also, these are [discussion] questions, they  aren't specifically asking "please change this" but "what should this be" -  they don't *necessarily* need a [status-complete], just an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 11):

[boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) works fine and fits with established conventions of things like [ac-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelations) which we have for Assassin's Creed: Revelations, which also exceeds the character limit.

Comment: Maybe we should request to have the tag length restriction removed for Arqade, since unlike most other sites, we have a valid need for long tags _(we also have might stricter tag restrictions)_

Comment: Just like to point out that it will need a synonym starting with "binding of isaac" (just like ac-revelations has) otherwise when a user starts typing in "Binding", it will not appear in the suggestions and thus will likely not be chosen.

Comment: @Aequitas if you start typing "Binding" you find "binding-of-isaac-rebirth" which is a suitable tag anyway.

Comment: @pinckerman if rebirth is suitable why is afterbirth tag needed?

Comment: Because Rebirth it's the game itself and must be used, Afterbirth is the expansion and its tag helps identifying the new features.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft This has been last raised on the main meta in [2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length). Anime.SE has similar problems, and I also recall some instances of 25 being too short over on RPG.SE. There were posts on [Portuguese](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/124/shouldn-t-the-tag-length-limit-be-relaxed-for-portuguese) and [here at Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters). Apparently, this change is not an easy one to do.