# How to tag “Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth+”?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/296798/binding-of-isaac-afterbirth-wont-start) asking about new DLC of *Binding of Isaac: Rebirth*, which is called **Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth+**.

The old DLC was tagged as [boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) so I tagged this one as [boi-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth%2b) but I'm not sure how to treat the "+" sign.

Is [boi-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth%2b) correct? Should I rename it [boi-afterbirth-plus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth-plus) instead?

Comment: The question received several downvotes and was probably deleted by the user, I can't find it now.

Comment: Related: [How to tag “Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10998/181240)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the official name is Afterbirth+, I believe you were correct in naming the tag [boi-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth%2b). If it becomes an issue, we could always make a tag synonym with [boi-afterbirth-plus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth-plus), but it should point to the former.

Comment: I was in doubt if that's actually a `+` or a `†` as written on the [wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Afterbirth_%E2%80%A0). Somewhere else is named [Afterbirth plus](http://platinumgod.co.uk/afterbirth-plus-info).

Comment: @pinckerman well, since the symbol they use is actually a cross, but they *call* it Afterbirth plus, I believe they're just using it as a stylized plus sign.

Comment: You're probably right..